# Permanently altering a user's %PATH% environment variable via batch or Python

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I've been having difficulty with getting my users to set the PATH environment variable manually, I'm looking for a way to do this automatically.  A batch file would be preferable, since that would require them to run it themselves (with a warning as to what they're doing), but an addition to the `setup.py` is acceptable as well.

Other information: `SET` only affects the current and derivative shells; the permanent values seem to be stored in the Registry somewhere (a place where I dare not tread).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As David said, there is the SETX tool that you can get from the Windows Resource Kit.

However, I have found that SETX has trouble (like crashing) sometimes. I have not figured out exactly what the problem is, but I suspect it is a size issue (for example if you try to set a variable—in my case it was PATH—to a value that is too big, eg >1024 some odd characters).

I have found two other executables that can do the same thing. My favorite in particular is **[*SetEnv*](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/SetEnv.aspx)** by Jonathan “Darka” Wilkes over at CodeProject. He has made it quite useful, with good functionality, and it is compatible with all Windows systems—I suggested some features too. :)

Another option, if you are up to it, is to do it manually (actually adding the item to the registry and then either broadcasting a *WM_SETTINGCHANGE* to top-level windows, or restarting the shell/rebooting). However I think that SetEnv in a BATCH file is your best bet. ;)

Comment: You still have to have them install SetEnv, but that's a relatively painless procedure.  This is looking to be the way I do it.

Comment: Well you don’t really have to *install* SetEnv, you can just have the executable in the same directory as the BATCH file that does the setting.

Comment: I finally got around to working on this.  Installed SetEnv in wine, pulled out the executable and threw it into my program dir, wrote a batch file to use it, and everything's gravy.

Answer (score 6):

> So, since I've been having difficulty with getting my users to set the PATH manually, I'm looking for a way to do this automatically.

The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (as well as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...`) registry key allows you to attach an *application specific path* to your executable name.

Whenever an executable of the given name is started, the *application specific path* is added to that executable's *PATH* environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran across this question and didn't like any of the available options so I decided to write my own solution.

(SetEnv would've been good, but I didn't like the non-libre license and I always prefer not having to call a subprocess... I wouldn't mind calling SetEnv as a subprocess but, according to Wikipedia, the license it uses is non-libre because it has some kind of "do no evil" clause and that kind of legally-ambiguous restriction is always a ticking time-bomb in my opinion.)

Here's a little [MIT-licensed Python class](https://gist.github.com/1009475) to hide away the work of modifying the registry directly and sending the WM_SETTINGCHANGE. (Good for use in `setup.py`)

Answer (score 2):

From this [website](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm#editing):

> Using the add-on tool Setx.exe
>
> It is not part of the standard Windows
>   XP setup but a command-line tool
>   called setx.exe is included in the
>   Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support
>   Tools. This tool extends the set
>   command so that permanent changes in
>   the environment variables can be made.
>   For example, to add a folder C:\New
>   Folder to the path, the command would
>   be
>
> ```
> setx path "%PATH%;C:\New Folder"
> ```

This sounds like it'll work for what you're wanting to do.