# How do you include %ProgramFiles% in PATH?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

According to  [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_install/how-to-use-programfiles-in-the-path-environment/48b23109-9fbc-47c5-a5d1-465773f94704)  it is not possible to include %ProgramFiles% in the path varaible, because windows environment variables get resolved in alphabetical order.

However, I need to be able to get the correct location of program files in PATH from a batch file (it can be expanded, I just can't hardcode the drive letter into the batch file because it needs to be portable). How do I do this?

EDIT: In response to some of the comments below, here is some additional information:
-The change to PATH needs to be permanent.
-SETX appears to just stick the literal %programfiles% in the path variable.

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying to do - what isn't working / how are you using the `%ProgramFiles%` variable?

Comment: When you say `windows environment variables get resolved in alphabetical order` the only place they are listed alphabetically is when executing the `set` command to simply list the variables.  There is no other sense of alpha sorting with environment variables.

Comment: @foxidrive: no, try setting two variables at system level `a` defined as `%systemroot%`, and `b` defined as `%a%`. Save, open cmd and try `SET`. Both variables have the same value. Now reverse, `a` defined as `%b%` and `b` defined as `%systemdrive%`. FAIL

Comment: @MCND Do you have a script to illustrate what you are trying to point out?

Comment: @foxidrive: no script, talking about system behaviour. How the environment variables defined at system level get initialized. If from `Computer` properties, `advanced options`, `environment variables`, system variables (path from memory, sorry), you include/change the variables as indicated, you will see the alphabetic problem in the initialization of the environment variables.

Comment: @foxidrive: to reproduce this behaviour from script changes to the registry are necessary (this can be done) but sending a WM_SETTINGSCHANGED to top level windows to inform of the change of variables so the effect can be seen without restarting/shutdown/explorer kill, can not be done from script (at least, at this moment i have no idea of how to do it without compiling code).

Comment: @mcnd So what you are saying is that on the OS bootup the system variables are managed from a-z or similar.   That doesn't apply to a cmd prompt, and isn't an issue in the PATH statement right?

Comment: @foxidrive: You are right. The roots of the problem is the fact you can not set the value of a variable in terms of another variable that still has not a value. It can't be done in a script nor in the system. As at boot time session environment variables definitions are retrieved from the registry alphabetically, variable `A` can not have a value derived from `B`, which still has not value. All the problem is the order of initialization of the variables. In a script you control it. In system boot, no. It's not a problem of the PATH statement, but in the PATH variable initial declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get `%ProgramFiles%` expanded when hand editing the PATH from the *Control Panel System* applet at system level.

But you can certainly use `%ProgramFiles%` in your BAT file. Just try

```
PATH %ProgramFiles%;%PATH%
```

If you want a permanent change in your PATH from a BAT file, then that's another question, already answered here [Permanently altering a user's %PATH% environment variable via batch or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156723/permanently-altering-a-users-path-environment-variable-via-batch-or-python)

Comment: Yes, you can. What you can't do is change it at system level using the `%programfiles%` variable. But if, at **user** level, from control panel system, you define a variable called `path` with the value of `%path%;%programfiles%`, and open a new instance of cmd, the path will contain a correct reference to the program files directory.

Comment: oh, didn't know this different behavior for user level. Edited.

Comment: I am looking for a permanent change, but using SETX (As suggested in the solution you linked to) just sticks the literal %programfiles% into the path. Ultimately it does not solve my problem.

Comment: ?) It works for me. Both in the command line and in the BAT. could you please post your actual code?

Comment: In the cmd file I was calling:

setx path "%ProgramFiles%\myfilepath" >> "%TEMP%\batchlog.txt

which, I am aware, does only modify the user path (since I left off the -m flag).

Comment: Just realized that I am being an idiot. I am running this batch file as a startup task in a Windows Azure Worker Role, and as a result there is no "real" user context. This would explain why I am getting such wonky behavior from my batch script lines that rely on user context.